# Java Threading writing and reading at the same value?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have thread A and Thread B , what would happen if A reads an int value in A(itself) to check a condtion , while B is writing to the same value at the same time would an error occur ? or just desynchronization ?

Comment: Writes to `int` are atomic. In fact, in practice, writes to `long` are atomic too - but not guaranteed to be. So the write is atomic, but not _visible_.

Comment: What @BoristheSpider means by "atomic":  When threads access an "atomic" variable with no synchronization, every read is guaranteed to get either the initial value, or a value that was stored by some other thread.  When unsynchronized threads access something (usually an object) that is _not_ atomic, there is no such guarantee:  Thread A could see a "value" that is a mix of bits that were written by two or more different threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described is called a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).  Each run of your program will have a different value stored in Thread A's memory where the result of the read is stored, all depending on the order of operations executed.

Answer (score 1):

No error, just unpredictable results. For that kind of operation use `AtomicInteger` or implement locking mechanism.